# Moving SharePoint MOSS Install

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I have a sharepoint MOSS 2007 Install on a server and need to move it to another new server. Can I just ghost the complete server to the new one or do I need to install and configure the complete server again?

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you will have to reinstall MOSS on the new server as during the configuration process many settings form the acutal server are stored to the MOSS configuration database. So just moving the MOSS software and database won't work. Even just renaming the server on which MOSS is running will probably lead to a MOSS error.

To make it easy to move MOSS to another server in the future you should think about visualization. By this you can move the server to every server you want just by installing the visualization software and moving the virtual machine to the new host server. 
This strategy will also help you in case of emergency when the MOSS server crashes due to a hardware error.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to do a clean install on the new machine.  This gives you the freedom to properly configure your machine(s) - name databases, pick ports for the Central Admin, SSP etc.

Resist the temptation to "upgrade" to a newer operating system (2003 to 2008), a new database (2000 - 2005 - 2008) or add service packs or the infrastructure update.  If it isn't installed on the current production system - then don't install it on your new machine.  Make a mirror of what you have and it will be much smoother.

Once the new server is configured the way you want it - just do a full backup from the Central Admin page on the old machine - and run a restore from the Central Admin on the new machine.  This will pick up all the customizations etc that you have on the old site.

Once it's restored - and you've tested it and it's working the way you expect, run a full backup from the Central Admin page on the new server.  That becomes your baseline for moving forward.